# How to close DriverManagerDataSource connection?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to close the connection of `DriverManagerDataSource` like the following:

```
public final class DbConnect {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DbConnect.class);

public static DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource(String dbHost, int dbPort, String dbUser, String dbPassword, String dbSID)
{
    LOG.info("getDataSource");
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

    ds.setUrl(String.format("jdbc:oracle:thin:@%s:%d:%s",  dbHost, dbPort, dbSID));
    LOG.info("url: " + ds.getUrl());
    ds.setUsername(dbUser);
    ds.setPassword(dbPassword);
    try {
        ds.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        LOG.info("Could not set db connecion to autocommit", e);
    }
    return ds;
}

/**
 * Test connection to Database
 * @param dbHost Database host name or IP
 * @param dbPort Database port number
 * @param dbUser Database user name
 * @param dbPassword Database password
 * @param dbSID Database service ID
 * @return true if connection successful or throws CmException in case of failure
 */
public static boolean testConnection(String dbHost, int dbPort, String dbUser, String dbPassword, String dbSID) throws CmException
{
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = getDataSource(dbHost, dbPort, dbUser, dbPassword, dbSID);
    JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    try {
        select.queryForInt("SELECT 1 from DUAL");
    } catch (Throwable ex){
        LOG.info("Could not connect to DB: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        throw new CmException(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        closeDBConnection(ds);
    }

    return true;
}

public static void closeDBConnection(DriverManagerDataSource ds) 
{
    LOG.debug("Close the DB connection");
    if(ds == null) { return; }
    try {
        LOG.debug("Getting the connection from data source");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if(conn != null) {
            LOG.debug("Try closing the connection");
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Could not close connection to DB: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

}
}

But notice that the connection isn't closed, does what I did is the correct way to close an opened connection? if no, how can I improve my code?

Comment: Have you tried a `try` with resources? Like `try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) { ... } catch (Exception ex) { ... }`? This should automatically close the connection.

Comment: You close connection on `Connection` not on `Datasource` either user `trywithresouce` or close it in `finally ` block

Comment: What is not working? What is even the purpose of this code? You're just creating a new connection and immediately closing it. What did you expect?

Comment: I've added the full code, where I've called the `closeConnection` method

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` closes it for you. Remove all that nasty stuff.